# PHP is right behavior?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

Is this right behavior for `php`?

tested on `PHP` Version `7.1.28` and `PHP` Version `7.2.13`
Why list changed? It's bug of `PHP` or I don't know something?

```
$label_list = explode(',', '1111, 22222, 33333');
foreach($label_list as &$label_item) {
    $label_item = trim(mb_strtolower($label_item));
}

var_dump($label_list); // source list
foreach ($label_list as $label_item) {
    var_dump($label_list); //? wtf list
}
```

result data:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(4) "1111"
  [1]=> string(5) "22222"
  [2]=> &string(5) "33333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(4) "1111"
  [1]=> string(5) "22222"
  [2]=> &string(4) "1111"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(4) "1111"
  [1]=> string(5) "22222"
  [2]=> &string(5) "22222"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(4) "1111"
  [1]=> string(5) "22222"
  [2]=> &string(5) "22222"
}
```

Why data in array changes? no changes inside cycle. Any explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug.
You used the same variable in both loops, but the first time you did it by reference and you did not unset it after the loop.
That means the next time you change the variable you change the source array.
Unset after you use by reference.

```
$label_list = explode(',', '111, 222, 333');
foreach($label_list as &$label_item) {
    $label_item = trim(mb_strtolower($label_item));
}
unset($label_item); // unset the by reference variable
var_dump($label_list); // source list
foreach ($label_list as $label_item) {
    var_dump($label_list); //? wtf list
}
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "222"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "222"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "222"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "222"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "333"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/MjlcU

If you look at your own output you see `&` at the last item.
That means it's by reference.

Comment: Agree. I think using force reference & is bad in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your second `foreach`, `$label_item` is the reference to the last element of `$label_list`, so it will set the last element of `$label_list` with the value of the first element of `$label_list`.

To avoid this, just add `unset($label_item)` before the second `foreach` to remove the reference to the last element of `$label_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Work without references. References have many pitfalls. Use the field keys to change field elements.

```
$label_list = explode(',', '1111, 22222, 33333');
foreach($label_list as $key => $label_item) {
    $label_list[$key] = trim(mb_strtolower($label_item));
}

var_dump($label_list); // source list
foreach ($label_list as $label_item) {
    var_dump($label_list); 
}
```